# Turning On compute engine VM instance automatically on a schedule without using cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm looking for a way to automatically turn On VM instance at a specific time. I know there is a [step by step guide](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule) from Google on how to do this using Cloud Scheduler, Cloud Functions & Cloud Pub/Sub, but my company wants everything to be stored on the Sydney server. Problem is, cloud functions [are not supported in Sydney](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations). So, I'm looking for a way on how to do this without cloud functions just using Cloud scheduler. Is there a way to do this? I would prefer the solution to be reliable, secure & possibly free. I need this run from the cloud so that I don't need some local machine running all the time that activates a script that turns On the VM instance. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want to achieve it is not as easy as appear. The term "easy" it is also relative so I will tell you my idea to overcome this situation.
 As you cannot use Cloud Functions and you want something free, or cheap at least, my suggestion is to use some Compute Engine instance to execute a script that start your stopped instances at some specific time, using cron daemon.

Maybe you have an instance that is never shutdown and can do the job. If you don't, you can use a f1-micro instance which is the cheapest one [available](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing?hl=en_US&_ga=2.78135956.-100352055.1549884144).

Then use a script like this:

```
for instance in  $(gcloud compute instances list --format="value(name)" --filter="status:terminated")
  do
    gcloud compute instances start $instance --zone=yourzone
  done
```

For examples related see [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/scripting-with-gcloud-a-beginners-guide-to-automating-gcp-tasks).
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I ended up making an application within app engine that turns the VM instance On & scheduled it using the app engine built in cron scheduler. Using app engine just for this task, it costs me nothing.